# Problem in Returning STR from Function in C

Tags: c, function, return

Hello and I'm sorry I don't speak English well.

I know this is repetitive But I Have a problem and i've never found the answer to my problem.

Shows this error whenever I compile this code by GCC :
code :

```
const char* myFunction()
{
    static char array[] = "my string";
    return array;
}
char a[101];
a=myFunction();
```

Error :

```
StackOverFlow.c: In function ‘main’:
StackOverFlow.c:51:2: error: assignment to expression with array type
   16 | a=myFunction();
      |  ^
```

When I use the return value of the function directly within printf Function, it doesn't make an error.

```
printf ("%s", myFunction());
```

i dont know what's it's problem.
sorry for Bad English.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays. You can make `a` a pointer though. Or copy the array *contents* (with `memcpy`, `strcpy` or similar).

Comment: such as `char *a = myFunction();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because, in C, this is the same as assigning the pointer to `array` to `a`, but you have already "initialized" `a`.

I don't know what you're try to achieve, but if you want to copy the string, use

```
strcpy(a, myFunction());
```

or, if you want the pointer, try

```
const char *a;
a=myFunction(); //If you try using printf with a it will work.
```